# Extjs 6 How to sum dates inside summaryType?

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a table in postgresql.
There is a field type of "interval" and its name is 'time_duration'. 
postgresql send to my extjs grid json like:

```
[{"id":"18","time_start":"2008-01-01 19:00:00+03","time_end":"2008-01-01 19:01:00+03","task":"test","task_type":"","date":"2017-07-03 00:00:00+03","task_result":"asdasd","username":"test_rakov","time_duration":"00:01:00"},{"id":"20","time_start":"2008-01-01 19:00:00+03","time_end":"2008-01-01 20:00:00+03","task":"asdasdasdasdsdf asdas","task_type":"","date":"2017-07-03 00:00:00+03","task_result":"asdasd","username":"test_rakov","time_duration":"01:00:00"},{"id":"21","time_start":"2008-01-01 12:00:00+03","time_end":"2008-01-01 14:00:00+03","task":"asdasdasdasdasd","task_type":"","date":"2017-07-03 00:00:00+03","task_result":"asdasd","username":"test_rakov","time_duration":"02:00:00"},{"id":"19","time_start":"2008-01-01 18:21:51+03","time_end":"2008-01-01 18:22:00+03","task":"asdasd","task_type":"","date":"2017-07-02 00:00:00+03","task_result":"","username":"test_rakov","time_duration":"00:00:09"}]
```

Id like to use `Ext.grid.feature.GroupingSummary`
When i use `summaryType: 'sum'` with `dataIndex: 'time_duration'` its return dates like a string and also add `0` at the start.
The `summaryType` gets in `value` parametr string `"0Tue Jul 04 2017 00:01:00 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима))Tue Jul 04 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима))Tue Jul 04 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима))"`. So the dates from json are joined.
Id like to sum them. For example `"time_duration":"01:00:00"+ "time_duration":"01:00:00" = "02:00:00"`.How to do it in right way? Mb change fields type in postgresl to something else? Help me please.

Here is my code:

```
 Ext.require(['Ext.data.*', 'Ext.grid.*']);

        // Создаем model
        Ext.define('Users', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            //idProperty: 'id',
            //idProperty: 'id',
            fields: [{
                    name: 'id',
                    type: 'int',
                    //mapping: 'id'
                },


                {
                    name:'time_duration',
                    type:'date',
                    dateFormat:'H:i:s'
                }
            ]
        });



        Ext.onReady(function() {
            // Создаем store
            var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                autoLoad: true,
                autoSync: true,
                model: 'Users',
                // Задает параметр для фильтрации подтаблиц myGroupingFeature
                groupField: 'date',
                groupDir: 'DESC',
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url: 'test_rakov.php',
                    api: {
                        create: 'test_rakov.php?action=create',
                        read: 'test_rakov.php?action=read',
                        update: 'test_rakov.php?action=update',
                        destroy: 'test_rakov.php?action=delete'
                    },
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        // Данные получаемые от сервера, которые мы затем обрабатываем в таблице
                        rootProperty: 'dataFromServer'
                    },
                    writer: {
                        type: 'json',
                        encode: true,
                        rootProperty: 'dataUpdate',
                        allowSingle: false,
                        writeAllFields: true,
                        //root:'records'
                    },
                    actionMethods: {
                        create: 'GET',
                        read: 'GET',
                        update: 'GET',
                        destroy: 'GET'

                    }
                },
                listeners: {
                    write: function(store, operation) {
                        var record = operation.getRecords()[0],
                            name = Ext.String.capitalize(operation.action),
                            verb;


                        if (name == 'Destroy') {
                            verb = 'Destroyed';
                        } else {
                            verb = name + 'd';
                        }
                        //Ext.example.msg(name, Ext.String.format("{0} user: {1}", verb, record.getId()));
                    }
                }
            });


            // Отображает подтаблицы в таблице
            var myGroupingFeature = Ext.create('Ext.grid.feature.GroupingSummary', {
                 groupHeaderTpl: '{columnName}: {name} ({rows.length} задач)',
                hideGroupedHeader: false,
                // Сворачивать по умолчанию или нет
                startCollapsed: false
            });


            //  Данные для выбора типа задачи
            var storeCombo = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
                fields: ["value"],
                data: [
                    ["Анализ регистраций в WebAdmin"],
                    ["AP -Анализ работы сервера"],
                    ["AP -Составление config файлов"],
                    ["Анализ заявок в СРМ"],
                    ["Встречи"],
                    ["Консультация сотрудников ОТП"],
                    ["Перекур"],
                    ["Программирование"],
                    ["Почтовая переписка"],
                    ["Другое"],
                ]
            });

            // Выбор типа задачи
            var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                store: storeCombo,
                editable: false,
                valueField: "value",
                displayField: "value",
            });

            var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                columnLines: true,
                renderTo: document.body,
                // Редактирование таблицы
                plugins: {
                    ptype: 'cellediting',
                    clicksToEdit: 1
                },
                listeners: {
                    edit: function() {

                    }
                },
                width: '99,3%',
                // Высота на весь экран
                autoHeight: true,
                frame: true,
                title: 'Users',
                store: store,
                // Отображает подтаблицы в таблице
                features: [myGroupingFeature],
                iconCls: 'icon-user',
                columns: [{
                        text: 'id',
                        width: '2%',
                        sortable: true,
                        dataIndex: 'id',
                        renderer: function(v, meta, rec) {
                            return rec.phantom ? '' : v;
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        header: 'Задача',
                        width: '30%',
                        // sortable: true,
                        dataIndex: 'task',
                        editor: {
                            completeOnEnter: false,
                            field: {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                enableKeyEvents: true,
                                listeners: {
                                    keydown: function(field, e) {
                                        if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
                                            field = grid.getSelectionModel().getCurrentPosition().rowIdx;
                                            grid.getView().focusRow(field);
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                //name: 'timeStart1',
                                //fieldLabel: 'Time In',
                                anchor: '100%',
                                allowBlank: false
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        header: 'Время начала',
                        width: '5%',
                        // sortable: true,
                        dataIndex: 'time_start',
                        //format: 'H:i',
                        // Нужно для верного отображеия времени после редактирования в таблице
                        renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('H:i'),
                        editor: {
                            completeOnEnter: true,
                            field: {
                                xtype: 'timefield',
                                format: 'Hi',
                                //name: 'timeStart1',
                                //fieldLabel: 'Time In',
                                //minValue: '8:00',
                                //maxValue: '20:00',
                                increment: 720,
                                //anchor: '100%',
                                //allowBlank: false
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        header: 'Результат',
                        width: '30%',
                        // sortable: true,
                        dataIndex: 'task_result',
                        editor: {
                            completeOnEnter: false,
                            field: {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                enableKeyEvents: true,
                                listeners: {
                                    keydown: function(field, e) {
                                        if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
                                            field = grid.getSelectionModel().getCurrentPosition().rowIdx;
                                            grid.getView().focusRow(field);
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                //name: 'timeStart1',
                                //fieldLabel: 'Time In',
                                //anchor: '100%',
                                allowBlank: false
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    {
                        header: 'Время конца',
                        width: '5%',
                        // sortable: true,
                        dataIndex: 'time_end',
                        //format: 'H:i',
                        // Нужно для верного отображеия времени после редактирования в таблице
                        renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('H:i'),
                        editor: {
                            completeOnEnter: false,
                            field: {
                                xtype: 'timefield',
                                format: 'Hi',
                                enableKeyEvents: true,
                                listeners: {
                                    keydown: function(field, e) {
                                        if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
                                            field = grid.getSelectionModel().getCurrentPosition().rowIdx;
                                            grid.getView().focusRow(field);
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                //name: 'timeStart1',
                                //fieldLabel: 'Time In',
                                minValue: '8:00',
                                maxValue: '20:00',
                                increment: 30,
                                anchor: '100%',
                                allowBlank: false
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        header: 'Дата',
                        width: 70,
                        // sortable: true,
                        dataIndex: 'date',
                        renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d/m/Y'),
                        editor: {
                            completeOnEnter: false,
                            field: {
                                xtype: 'datefield',
                                dateFormat: 'd/m/Y',
                                allowBlank: false
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        header: 'Длительность',
                        width: 60,
                        // sortable: true,
                        dataIndex: 'time_duration',
                        //xtype: 'datecolumn',
                        renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('H:i:s'),
                        summaryType: 'sum',
                        //summaryType: function(f1){ console.log(f1); return;}
                        //summaryRenderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('H:i')

                        summaryRenderer: function(value, summaryData, dataIndex){
                            //console.log("val1= " + value);
                            var val2 = value.substring(1);
                            //console.log("val2= " + x);
                            var x = Ext.Date.format(val2, 'H:i:s');
                            //console.log (x);
                            //console.log( Ext.Date.format(val2, 'H:i:s'));
                             //console.log("tmpDate= " + tmpDate);
                            //return Ext.String.format('{0} student{1}', value, value !== 1 ? 's': '');
                        }

                    },
                    {
                        header: 'Тип задачи',
                        width: '20%',
                        dataIndex: 'task_type',
                        editor: combo
                    }
                ],
                dockedItems: [{
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    items: [{
                        text: 'Добавить задачу',
                        iconCls: 'icon-add',
                        handler: function() {
                            // Создаем новую задачу
                            // Для корректной работы с БД нужно задать ID новой строки, равной +1 от последней ID из таблицы.
                            var rec = new Users();

                            //rec.date = Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'Y-m-d\\T00:00:00');
                            //rec.data.date = Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'Y-m-d\\T00:00:00');
                            rec.set('date', new Date());
                            rec.set('time_start', new Date(),'H:i:s');

                            //rec.time_start = Ext.Date.format(new Date(), '2008-01-01\\TH:i:s');
                            //rec.data.time_start = Ext.Date.format(new Date(), '2008-01-01\\TH:i:s');
                            store.insert(0, rec);

                        }
                    }, '-', {
                        itemId: 'delete',
                        text: 'Удалить задачу',
                        iconCls: 'icon-delete',
                        disabled: false,
                        handler: function() {
                            var selection = grid.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
                            if (confirm('Вы действительно хотите удалить задачу №' + selection.id + " ?")) {
                                // Удлаяем      
                                if (selection) {
                                    store.remove(selection);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }]
            });
        });
```

Comment: Well, here is the problem, you can't sum dates. What does it mean for example to sum (01/01/2001T03:49:41 + 01/01/2002T00:00:00) ? A better idea would be to have time_duration type as a number field represented in seconds and then use the summaryRenderer to show the values as hours:minutes:seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `summaryType` a function:

> .... Alternatively, the summaryType can be a function definition. If
>   this is the case, the function is called with two parameters: an array
>   of records, and an array of field values to calculate the summary
>   value.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.feature.GroupingSummary.html

So instead of:

```
summaryType: 'sum'
```

You can use:

```
summaryType: function(records){
  // do your logic and return a value.
}
```